# From project without framework to zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, architecture, zend-framework2

I started a project without using any framework.

My project structure was something like this:

- A folder with classes to access my DB
- A folder with classes for business logic
- A folder with classes that can help me do other stuff
- A folder with php pages that can be called inside pages(eg: navbar, footer, etc)
- On root I had my php pages

So, calling all classes was preety easy.  Now i am creating a new zf2 project and want to move all my work to this new project.I already setup the layouts and content of each page but i'm having some problems adding my custom classes. **Should I use other kind of organization? Where can/should create my custom classes?**

I also have some "php files" where I check some user info and depending on that, show him oriented advertisement. On my old project I was just calling it with "require"... can I do this on ZF2?/ is this the proper way to do it?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be helpful http://modules.zendframework.com/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same question.

I created my custom library inside the vendor folder.

Here are some useful links:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/psr-duh--net-31061

http://ulaptech.blogspot.pt/2014/02/adding-3rd-party-libraries-to-zend.html

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 follows the MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern.
So your directory structure looks like

module
    
       
          
            
                Entity.php
                EntityInterface.php
            
                Table.php
                TableInterface.php
                TableFactory.php

The basic access methods are in Table.php
The mapping between columns and array is in Entity.php

If you would consult the tutorial Album application on the Zendframework website, you will see a working example.